# Why neural network suddenly converges to fixed result?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm using tensorflow to train MLP & CNN with AdamOptimizer as a default parameters.
I found that it works well but after some training step, it converges to fixed results.
For example, there's only two categories,

```
training step 0: 0.5
training step 1000:0.9
training step 2000: 0.953
..........
training step 100000: 0.99995
training step 110000: 0.5
.................
training step 200000: 0.5
```

after some step, it is converged to some values that indicating all label1 or all label2

What is the reason and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you provide some information about the actual problem you are trying to solve? How many classes are there, how many samples per class etc. And what the above numbers (`0.5`, `0.953`, etc) represent also.

Answer (score 0):

Because no code is posted, we can only presume likely asnswers. In my experience, when something like this happens (e.g. training collapses) this has to do with some kind of overflow in the network. Do you have training examples that produce nans? Plotting the output of your network shortly before it diverges helps with that problem. Does your network overflow? Plotting the gradient norm is helpful here. If it goes toward infinity you suffer from exploding gradient.

However, without code, konwledge of the domain, training data or anything at all this is just a guessing game.